# Snapping nearby SceneKit objects

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am trying to make a simple marble game where you have marble track pieces and you snap them together to build a track to your liking.

Mixing curved, straight and sloped tracks

I’m struggling to figure out how to handle snapping pieces together when they get close

Since the user would be dragging new tracks around in a 3D world vía a 2d interface when the tracks get close I would want them to snap together until the user pulls too far away again

What is the best way to go about this snapping logic?

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: No, I have not yet

Comment: Any solution found for this?